# Wordpress Login Logout Custom Function Error

Tags: php, css, wordpress, function

I'm using avada and added this line of codes in the `functions.php`

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      echo "
  <style>
    .loggedin { display:none; visibility: hidden;}
    .loggedout { display:block;visibility: visible;}
  </style>
  ";
} else {
      echo "
  <style>
    .loggedin { display:block; visibility: visible; }
    .loggedout { display:none; visibility: hidden;}
  </style>
  ";
}
?>
```

Basically, what it does is hide the LOGOUT menu when user is logged in and vice versa.

It works but it conflicts with MEDIA GALLERY -- i can't upload files...

Please help!

Comment: If you are using display:none and display block, you dont really need the visibility in your CSS. Not fixing the problem but cleaning the code

Comment: What do you mean by I can't upload files, what error message are you getting?

Comment: by adding those line of codes in the functions.php -- when you upload images it's stuck in crunching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid using PHP to stuff that could be done in CSS.

Most Wordpress template prints CSS **classes** for what is commonly native Wordpress behavior.

Example for me when i am logged-in this appears in the body.

```
<body class="home page page-id-318 page-template-default logged-in">
```

Notice the logged-in class.

If i am not logged-in it doesn't print out.

So you could do this toggle effect on page load with CSS just by selecting the class and have it hidden by default.

```
.some-class {
display:none; 
visibility: hidden;
}

.logged-in .some-class{
display:block; 
visibility: visible;
}
```

If you were to use PHP itself it should be to prevent the markup from the displaying in the source itself. Which you could do lets say its a menu holding the loggin/loggout you could do `add_filter()` to prevent the markup from outputting.

On a side note if you have common classes that are interfering you could make a custom CSS class and apply it to the elements with a filter also.

> https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Adding_Conditional_Classes_to_Menu_Items